# How to call a static variable from another class in Inner nested classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a constant file in python and i need to use a nested classes to declare some static variables within. Some of those variables use another variables from another inner class the problem is when i try to call that static variable a NameError shows up "name 'MyClass1' is not defined.
this is an example:

```
class MyOutterClass:

  class MyClass1:
    myStaticVar1 = 5

  class myClass2:
    myStaticVar2 = MyClass1.myStaticVar1 * 2
```

the error message is in myStaticVar2 : NameError: name 'myClass1' is not defined.

do you guys have any solution or any 'work around' way to solve this problem and could you please tell me what causes this problem! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you "need" to use nested classes for this?

Comment: nested classes here are for the constants variable that me or another developer need to use, for example i have a function that accept some arguments, those arguments  must be is pre-defined (the user doesn't need to know about the actual value) it's enough for him to use this constant file to find what he looking for in a hierarchical way. Example: Arduino.GPIO.PORT.pin1, this argument represent the pin address that he don't need to know what is it to configure it as input or output.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you feel you have to use nested classes for this, rather than dictionaries or enums or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in class scope are not accessible within other scopes nested in the class scope.  In your example, `MyClass1` is a variable in the class scope of `MyOuterClass`.  Within the body of `MyClass2` a new scope is created which does not have access to the enclosing class's scope, hence your error.

I don't really see a reason to use nested classes for this.  You can just use dictionaries, or some kind of dictionary that provides attribute-style access (such as [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace).

Comment: for the moment i'm keeping it like this (nested classes) and i will try to avoid call a variable from another class just to speed up the work and move on.but thank you for you suggestion, i think i'm going to use it or use the collection lib (namedtuple) later, in another version of the project.